# Suppose $f'(x)>c>0$ for all $x\in[0,\infty)$, show $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

I have from the definition of the derivative that for all $x_0\in [x,\infty)$ $$f'(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$
exists and is larger than some positive constant $c$. Intuitively, this problem is obvious, of course if the derivative is strictly positive then the function must be increasing, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

I thought maybe I could use the mean value theorem and show since $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ it is continuous on an interval $[x,x+1]$ and then for some $a$ in that interval $$f'(a)=f(x+1)-f(x)>c>0$$ $$f(x+1)>f(x)$$ but this doesn't seem to be quite enough. Any hints or other ideas appreciated!

Comment: You're almost there: note that your argument gives the stronger bound $f(x+1)>c+f(x)$. Now iterate this. What can you say of $f(x+n) $ for $n$ a positive integer with respect to $f(x) $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the mean value theorem does work! Apply it to $[0,x]$ and use the fact that mean value is always less than or equal to the max value.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**

$$f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^x f'(t)\,dt>f(0)+cx$$

Comment: Isn't there a $f(0)$ missing after the $>$?

Comment: @Stefano Yes, there was. I've edited.   Thank you for the catch.  -Mark

Comment: While this is a slick approach, it does assume integrability of $f'$. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, indeed.  Volterra's function is an example of a function whose derivative is bounded, but not integrable.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach with the same conclusion: please apply the Mean Value Theorem to the interval $[0,x]$.